# Rails 3 - Devise Sign up and Sign in view together (multiple redirects)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to set up a Sign up and Sign in page at the same view and at the root url.

I did this by changing the users/sessions/new view (devise generated view) to put in there the 2 forms (Sign up and Sign in).

So far so good, but I have 2 problems:

First, when I try to sign up and have invalid data, it redirects me to mywebapp/users, while it should redirect to the same page mywebapp/ (the root_path).

Second, if I try to sign in, it successfully does that, and redirect to the proper url (root_path also), but it keeps trying to redirect to it over and over, and I get the error "Too many redirects to http://localhost...".

My routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users do
  root :to => "devise/sessions#new"
end
```

My users/sessions/new.rb:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= render 'users/sessions/home' %>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'users/sessions/login' %>
<% end %>
```

My _login.rb partial:

```
 <h1>Index</h1>
 <hr/>

 <h2>Log in</h2>
 <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td><%= f.label :email %></td>
       <td><%= f.email_field :email %></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td><%= f.label :password %></td>
       <td><%= f.password_field :password %></td>
     </tr>
   </table>

   <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
     <%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
   <% end %>

   <div><%= f.submit "Log in" %></div>
<% end %>

<% if devise_mapping.recoverable? %>
  <%= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(resource_name) %><br/>
<% end %>

<hr/>

<h2>Sign up</h2>
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><%= f.label :first_name %></td>
      <td><%= f.text_field :first_name %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><%= f.label :last_name %></td>
      <td><%= f.text_field :last_name %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><%= f.label :email %></td>
      <td><%= f.email_field :email %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><%= f.label :password %></td>
      <td><%= f.password_field :password %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><%= f.label :password_confirmation %></td>
      <td><%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

My _home partial is just an empty view for now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**First problem**: Please use `rails generate devise:views` command which will create devise views for you in views/devise folder ([configuring views](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views)). You can put render partial in views:

`views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb` (sign up)

and

`views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb` (sign in).

**Second problem**: You set root_path to devise/sessions#new and if you sign in correct devise try to redirect to root_path again and again. You need to set some another root_path and if you want to denied access for not authenticated users, you can just add filter to controller ([Devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers)) and devise redirect these users to authenticate page for you:

`before_action :authenticate_user!` (Rails 3) or `before_filter :authenticate_user!` (Rails 3)

Comment: can you elaborate on how to call 'render partial' the devise views are not partials. Are you suggesting to make them into partials and render them in a single view?

Comment: If you want to have sign in/out forms on one page, you can modify ../registrations/new.html.erb and ../sessions/new.html.erb pages to put render partial with both forms in them. Both new.html.erb should have the same forms (my proposition is to use partial view).

Comment: @MichałZalewski Did you find a solution to your problem? Please share if you would like to.